# ConTeXt: Cross-reference from macro definition

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, context, xml

## Background

Looking to allow user-defined cross-references and captions. The input XML resembles:

```html
<p>
  <a class="name" data-type="tab" name="ref"/>
</p>
<table>...</table>
<p>
  See <a class="href" data-type="tab" href="#ref"/> for details.
</p>
```

Note how `ref` and `#ref` differ (due to how HTML anchor links work). The `#` must be trimmed, which I've done (shown in the problem section, below).

### System

ConTeXt version 2023.09.26 18:19.

## Problem

The `AnchorXref` and `xmlatt` macros cannot be used for cross-references. That is, the following doesn't work:

```tex
\startbuffer[main]
<body>
<p><a class="name" data-type="tab" name="ref"/></p>
<table>a table</table>
<p>See <a class="href" data-type="tab" href="#ref"/> for details.</p>
</body>
\stopbuffer

\def\removefirst#1{\expandafter\removefirstA#1\removefirstA}
\def\removefirstA#1#2\removefirstA{#2}

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body|p|table}{xml:*}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{a[@class='name']}{xml:anchorname}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{a[@class='href']}{xml:anchorhref}

  \define\AnchorName{}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:table
  (name = '\AnchorName')

  \startplacetable[title={Table caption.}, reference={\AnchorName}]
    \startembeddedxtable
      \startxtablebody[body]
        \startxrow
          \startxcell
            Cell content
          \stopxcell
        \stopxrow
      \stopxtablebody
    \stopembeddedxtable
  \stopplacetable
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:anchorname
  \define\AnchorName{\xmlatt{#1}{data-type}:\xmlatt{#1}{name}}
\stopxmlsetups

% Make a reference to a given anchor.
\startxmlsetups xml:anchorhref
  \define\AnchorXref{\xmlatt{#1}{data-type}:\removefirst{\xmlatt{#1}{href}}}
  \in[\AnchorXref]

  \ (xref = '\AnchorXref')
\stopxmlsetups

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{main}{main}{}
\stoptext
```

Produces (note the `??`):

[image: Table reference 1]

Using a simple macro definition works:

```tex
\starttext
  \chapter{Chapter}

  \define\AnchorXref{tab:ref}

  \startplacetable[title={Table caption.}, reference=\AnchorXref]
    \startembeddedxtable
      \startxtablebody[body]
        \startxrow
          \startxcell
            Table cell
          \stopxcell
        \stopxrow
      \stopxtablebody
    \stopembeddedxtable
  \stopplacetable

  See \in[\AnchorXref].
\stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Table reference 2]

## Question

What needs to change to allow for macro expansion?

## Related

- [ConTeXt the manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-enp.pdf), section 9.5
- [References](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/References)

Comment: `\define` creates a protected command (`\protected\def`) which isn't expandable, the expandable version of `\define` is `\defineexpandable`.

Comment: To get the reference without the leading hash you can use the `\xmlrefatt` command, e.g. `\xmlrefatt{#1}{href}`.

Comment: When mixing table and figure captions alongside cross-references, I couldn't get the expandable technique to work. Rather, `\setvariable{Reference}{caption}` and `\getvariable{Reference}{caption}` keeps the values straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\defineexpandable` is key and `\xmlrefatt` will automatically handle the `#` character:

```tex
\startbuffer[main]
<body>
<p><a class="name" data-type="tab" name="ref"/></p>
<table>a table</table>
<p>See <a class="href" data-type="tab" href="#ref"/> for details.</p>
</body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body|p|table}{xml:*}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{a[@class='name']}{xml:anchorname}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{a[@class='href']}{xml:anchorhref}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:table
  \startplacetable[title={Table caption.}, reference={\AnchorName}]
    \startembeddedxtable
      \startxtablebody[body]
        \startxrow
          \startxcell
            Cell content
          \stopxcell
        \stopxrow
      \stopxtablebody
    \stopembeddedxtable
  \stopplacetable
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:anchorname
  \defineexpandable\AnchorName{\xmlatt{#1}{data-type}:\xmlatt{#1}{name}}
\stopxmlsetups

% Make a reference to a given anchor.
\startxmlsetups xml:anchorhref
  \defineexpandable\AnchorXref{\xmlatt{#1}{data-type}:\xmlrefatt{#1}{href}}

  Table \in[\AnchorXref]
\stopxmlsetups

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{main}{main}{}
\stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Table reference 3]